# 0xc000007b error on Unreal Engine 4

Tags: crash, 32bit-64bit, unreal-engine4

I have recently downloaded Unreal Engine 4 from its official site and tried to start it but got this error.

[image: 0xc000007b error]

I tried to google solutions and found some but didn't work for me. Few of theme were related to xinput1_3.dll file and some were related to c++.

- Solution for xinput1_3.dll was to convert its version of 32bit to 64bit.
- Solution for c++ was same as above, 32bit to 64bit.

  *Specification*

  - Windows 10 64bit
  - Core2Duo 3.0Ghz
  - 5GB Ram
  - *Don't worry about Graphic Card*.

Comment: This is better asked on the Epic support forums as it's got more to do with system libraries than programming directly.  Also your system doesn't meet minimum system requirements, even without knowing the GPU.

Comment: @trojanfoe does it mean this issue is because of it?

Comment: I would say so, yes.  But Epic Games will be able to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the **msvcr120.dll** and **msvcp120.dll** files, after that repair the VC++ Redistributable installation.

It worked for me

[Source](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/18335/cant-install-error-0xc000007b.html)

Comment: There are number of versions of _VC++ Redistributable_, which version are you talking about.

Comment: You can repair all of them because you are not sure which one needs to be repaired, or you can use dependency walker to exactly check which DLLs are missing and then you can only replace those instead of repairing all versions. http://www.dependencywalker.com/depends22_x64.zip